# asp.net mvc. Display html string from database

Tags: database, asp.net-mvc, string, razor

I need to display a data from a database which contains strings like &amp; or &laquo;. When I try to display them through *Html.Raw* or *Html.Encode*, I've got dublicates values like &amp; for *Html.Raw* and also bad output for *Html.Encode*.

What should I try? I use Razor syntax.

Example string: **Hello, my name is Junior &amp; I hate &laquo;bugs&raquo;**.

Comment: I think what you want to do is *`Decode()`*, not either of the above. And doesn't MVC automatically do that with the `<%: %>` syntax?

Comment: @Cory: `<%: %>` is not Razor syntax...

Comment: @JeremyHolovacs: Ahh, thanks. I've not had the pleasure of doing much MVC work :(

Comment: the `@Html.Raw(string)` should be the proper syntax.  Are you sure the string data in the database is not already escaped?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I've got a bad string in a database.

Comment: I don't know how to mark your answer as helpful, so just thank you very much.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As per the comments at the top:

the `@Html.Raw(string)` should be the proper syntax. Are you sure the string data in the database is not already escaped?